# Can't compile - Undefined control sequence

Tags: thesis, report, documentclass

I am writing my thesis, and I can't understand what is the problem because the spelling seems correct to me. Maybe its the `report` document class that is the problem. I really don't understand.

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{Data sharing in the European Union: data spaces}
\author{xxxx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{
        natbib=true,
        %style=authoryear-comp,
        style=apa,
        backend=biber,
        url=false,
        doi=false,
        isbn=false,
        eprint=false,
            }{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/home/enrico/Università/uni_bib.bib}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{import} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
        a4paper,
        total={170mm, 257 mm},
        left=20mm,
        top=20mm,
}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
    \chapter{Introduction}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the error:

```
Università/MAGISTRALE/Thesis/final_writing/masters_thesis.tex|42 error| Undefined control sequence.
Università/MAGISTRALE/Thesis/final_writing/masters_thesis.tex|42 warning| Package microtype Warning: Unable to apply patch `footnote' on input line 42.
```

Line 42 is where the `\begin{document}` is.

**SOLUTION**: Either delete the `\usepackage{transparent}` or the `\usepackage{pstricks}` line because those packages seems to not work well together (with `pdflatex`).

Comment: `\usepackage{transparent}` is responsible for this. Works fine if I comment it out (and use some dummy bibliography).

Comment: Thank you! But why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only showed a fragment of the error message, so did not show which command was undefined.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs ...urce@extgs@plain 
                                                  {#1}
l.42 \begin{document}
                     
?
```

which is not terribly informative but shows the problem is in pgf backend code, that also explains the warnings

```
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> header=pst-algparser.pro
```

from pstricks

Running with latex rather than pdflatex runs without error.

Comment: I used the errors from ```vim-tex```, my bad. However, if I delete ```\usepackage{transparent}``` as suggested by [Outis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/237192/%ce%9f%e1%bd%96%cf%84%ce%b9%cf%82), it compiles without problems. Do you know why does this happen?

Comment: @enrico223 transparency in pdf is tricky and needs access to the global state object `gs` error message... There is only one of those so packages tend to conflict. The new core latex pdf-management code should improve things here but it is work in progress, meanwhile you have to be optimstic or lucky to load pgf, pstricks, transparency, ... all at the same time. pstricks basically will never work in pdflatex.